# How to prioritize/rank FilteredList results within a predicate?

Tags: java, javafx, predicate

My application contains a `TextField` and a `ListView`. The `TextField` allows users to enter search terms that will filter the contents of the `ListView` as they type.

The filtering process will match several fields within each `DataItem` in the `ListView` and return the results if any of them match.

What I want to do, however, is have those results prioritize items that match one particular field over the others.

For example, in the MCVE below, I have two items: `Computer` and `Paper`.  The `Computer` item has a `keyword` for "paper," so searching for "paper" should return `Computer` as a result.

However, since I also have an item called `Paper`, the search should return `Paper` at the top of the list.  In the MCVE, though, the results are still alphabetized:

[image: Screenshot]

**Question:** How would I go about ensuring any matches to the `DataItem.name` are listed above matches to a `DataItem.keywords`?

**EDIT:** Entering "pap" in the search field should also return "Paper" at the top, followed by the remaining matches, as the partial search term partially matches the `DataItem` name.

---

> **MCVE**

---

**DataItem.java:**

```
import java.util.List;

public class DataItem {

    // Instance properties
    private final IntegerProperty id = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
    private final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private final StringProperty description = new SimpleStringProperty();

    // List of search keywords
    private final ObjectProperty<List<String>> keywords = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

    public DataItem(int id, String name, String description, List<String> keywords) {
        this.id.set(id);
        this.name.set(name);
        this.description.set(description);
        this.keywords.set(keywords);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a space-separated String of all the keywords; used for filtering later
     */
    public String getKeywordsString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (String keyword : keywords.get()) {
            sb.append(keyword).append(" ");
        }

        return sb.toString();

    }

    public int getId() {
        return id.get();
    }

    public IntegerProperty idProperty() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name.get();
    }

    public StringProperty nameProperty() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description.get();
    }

    public StringProperty descriptionProperty() {
        return description;
    }

    public List<String> getKeywords() {
        return keywords.get();
    }

    public ObjectProperty<List<String>> keywordsProperty() {
        return keywords;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name.get();
    }
}
```

---

**Main.java:**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.collections.transformation.FilteredList;
import javafx.collections.transformation.SortedList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class Main extends Application {

    // TextField used for filtering the ListView
    TextField txtSearch = new TextField();

    // ListView to hold our DataItems
    ListView<DataItem> dataItemListView = new ListView<>();

    // The ObservableList of DataItems
    ObservableList<DataItem> dataItems;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // Simple Interface
        VBox root = new VBox(10);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        // Add the search field and ListView to the layout
        root.getChildren().addAll(txtSearch, dataItemListView);

        // Build the dataItems List
        dataItems = FXCollections.observableArrayList(buildDataItems());

        // Add the filter logic
        addSearchFilter();

        // Show the stage
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Sample");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * Adds the functionality to filter the list dynamically as search terms are entered
     */
    private void addSearchFilter() {

        // Wrap the dataItems list in a filtered list, initially showing all items, alphabetically
        FilteredList<DataItem> filteredList = new FilteredList<>(
                dataItems.sorted(Comparator.comparing(DataItem::getName)));

        // Add the predicate to filter the list whenever the search field changes
        txtSearch.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) ->
                filteredList.setPredicate(dataItem -> {

                    // Clear any selection already present
                    dataItemListView.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();

                    // If the search field is empty, show all DataItems
                    if (newValue == null || newValue.isEmpty()) {
                        return true;
                    }

                    // Compare the DataItem's name and keywords with the search query (ignoring case)
                    String query = newValue.toLowerCase();

                    if (dataItem.getName().toLowerCase().contains(query)) {
                        // DataItem's name contains the search query
                        return true;
                    } else {

                        // Otherwise check if any of the search terms match those in the DataItem's keywords
                        // We split the query by space so we can match DataItems with multiple keywords
                        String[] searchTerms = query.split(" ");
                        boolean match = false;
                        for (String searchTerm : searchTerms) {
                            match = dataItem.getKeywordsString().toLowerCase().contains(searchTerm);
                        }
                        return match;
                    }
                }));

        // Wrap the filtered list in a SortedList
        SortedList<DataItem> sortedList = new SortedList<>(filteredList);

        // Update the ListView
        dataItemListView.setItems(sortedList);
    }

    /**
     * Generates a list of sample products
     */
    private List<DataItem> buildDataItems() {

        List<DataItem> dataItems = new ArrayList<>();

        dataItems.add(new DataItem(
                1, "School Supplies", "Learn things.",
                Arrays.asList("pens", "pencils", "paper", "eraser")));
        dataItems.add(new DataItem(
                2, "Computer", "Do some things",
                Arrays.asList("paper", "cpu", "keyboard", "monitor")));
        dataItems.add(new DataItem(
                3, "Keyboard", "Type things",
                Arrays.asList("keys", "numpad", "input")));
        dataItems.add(new DataItem(
                4, "Printer", "Print things.",
                Arrays.asList("paper", "ink", "computer")));
        dataItems.add(new DataItem(
                5, "Paper", "Report things.",
                Arrays.asList("write", "printer", "notebook")));

        return dataItems;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If not mistaken you only need to find a way to sort your filtered results correctly. To keep it simple I will use this comparator instead of yours :

```
Comparator<DataItem> byName = new Comparator<DataItem>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(DataItem o1, DataItem o2) {
                String searchKey = txtSearch.getText().toLowerCase();
                int item1Score = findScore(o1.getName().toLowerCase(), searchKey);
                int item2Score = findScore(o2.getName().toLowerCase(), searchKey);

                if (item1Score > item2Score) {
                    return -1;
                }

                if (item2Score > item1Score) {
                    return 1;
                }

                return 0;
            }

            private int findScore(String itemName, String searchKey) {
                int sum = 0;
                if (itemName.startsWith(searchKey)) {
                    sum += 2;
                }

                if (itemName.contains(searchKey)) {
                    sum += 1;
                }
                return sum;
            }
        };
```

In the code above, I compare two DataItem. Each one will have a 'score' which depends on how similar their names are from our search keyword. For simplicity lets say we give 1 point if the `searchKey` appeared in the name of our item and 2 points if the item name starts with the `searchKey`, so now we can compare those two and sort them. If we return -1 the item1 will be placed first, if we return 1 then the item2 will be placed first and return 0 otherwise.

Here is `addSearchFilter()` method I used in your example :

```
private void addSearchFilter() {
        FilteredList<DataItem> filteredList = new FilteredList<>(dataItems);

        txtSearch.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> filteredList.setPredicate(dataItem -> {

            dataItemListView.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();

            if (newValue == null || newValue.isEmpty()) {
                return true;
            }

            String query = newValue.toLowerCase();

            if (dataItem.getName().toLowerCase().contains(query)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                String[] searchTerms = query.split(" ");
                boolean match = false;
                for (String searchTerm : searchTerms) {
                    match = dataItem.getKeywordsString().toLowerCase().contains(searchTerm);
                }
                return match;
            }
        }));

        SortedList<DataItem> sortedList = new SortedList<>(filteredList);

        Comparator<DataItem> byName = new Comparator<DataItem>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(DataItem o1, DataItem o2) {
                String searchKey = txtSearch.getText().toLowerCase();
                int item1Score = findScore(o1.getName().toLowerCase(), searchKey);
                int item2Score = findScore(o2.getName().toLowerCase(), searchKey);

                if (item1Score > item2Score) {
                    return -1;
                }

                if (item2Score > item1Score) {
                    return 1;
                }

                return 0;
            }

            private int findScore(String itemName, String searchKey) {
                int sum = 0;
                if (itemName.startsWith(searchKey)) {
                    sum += 2;
                }

                if (itemName.contains(searchKey)) {
                    sum += 1;
                }
                return sum;
            }
        };

        sortedList.setComparator(byName);

        dataItemListView.setItems(sortedList);
    }
```

Of course the `findScore()` could be more sophisticated if you want to create a more complex score system (for example checking upper and lower case letters, give more points depending the position of the keyword found in the item name etc).

Comment: This is simply brilliant! Thank you so much. My own solution "works," but yours went many steps beyond to actually "rank" the items with a `Comparator`. I am not too familiar with predicates and Comparators, but I think I understand them better now. Feels like I have a mini-Google in my app now :) Thank you.

Comment: @Zephyr I am glad I was able to help. To be honest I wasn't aware about predicates at all so your example helped me to learn something new as well ;)

Comment: @Zephyr Just to add options: A more "sophisticated" (if needed) ranking could be done by calculating [Levenshtien distances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) (or other similar algorithms) and have shorter distances be considered "less than" by the `Comparator`. The [commons-text](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/) library by Apache has [implementations](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/index.html) of various edit distance algorithms.

Comment: Thanks for `setComparator` in `sortedList`. I was using `sortedList.sortWith(comparator)` and it crashed

Answer (score 2):

I may have found a different way to accomplish this. Instead of using a `Predicate`, I've changed the `ChangeListener` to just use a couple of loops and build a new `List` manually:

```
    txtSearch.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {

        if (newValue == null || newValue.isEmpty()) {
            // Reset the ListView to show all items
            dataItemListView.setItems(dataItems);
            return;
        }

        ObservableList<DataItem> filteredList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        String query = newValue.toLowerCase().trim();

        // First, look for exact matches within the DataItem's name
        for (DataItem item : dataItems) {
            if (item.getName().toLowerCase().contains(query)) {
                filteredList.add(0, item);
            } else {

                // If the item's name doesn't match, we'll look through search terms instead
                String[] searchTerms = query.split(" ");
                for (String searchTerm : searchTerms) {
                    // If the item has this searchTerm and has not already been added to the filteredList, add it
                    // now
                    if (item.getKeywordsString().toLowerCase().contains(searchTerm)
                            && !filteredList.contains(item)) {
                        filteredList.add(item);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        dataItemListView.setItems(filteredList);
```

I'll leave the question unanswered for now to see if anyone has a solution for using the `Predicate` as well.